# SAS: how to save multiple ODS output from a %DO loop

Tags: sas

```
data scores;
   length name $ 12;
   input name $ score1 score2;
   datalines;
Riley 1132 1187
Henderson 1015 1102
;

%MACRO DO_MEAN;
%DO I = 1 %TO 10;
 PROC MEANS data = scores;
 VAR score1;
 TITLE "Average math score";
 RUN;
%END;
%MEND DO_MEAN; 

ods output Summary = Summary;
%DO_MEAN;
```

I have a simple macro called `%DO_MEAN` that calculates the mean `score1` in my dataset. I want the macro to run from i = 1 to 10 times.

Invoking the macro outputs the results of the MEANS procedure 10 times. And yes, I know the output is exactly the same, but I just wanted to use this reproducible example for the sake of illustration.

I tried using `ods output Summary = Summary;` before invoking the macro to store my 10 outputs. However, the resulting `Summary` dataset only has 1 row. How can I adjust my code so that I can store all 10 outputs?

[image]

I'd like the resulting ods dataset above to have 10 rows, each corresponding to one of %DO loop's iterations.

Comment: See my answer to your other question. Don't do it this way in the first place. There's a good paper out there on simulation using SAS - Don't be loopy by David Cassell. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PERSIST option on the ODS OUTPUT statement, documented here:
http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=odsug&docsetTarget=p0oxrbinw6fjuwn1x23qam6dntyd.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

```
ods output parameterestimates (persist=proc) = want;
proc reg data=sashelp.class;
where sex='F';
model height = weight;
run;

proc reg data=sashelp.class;
where sex='M';
model height = weight;
run;

quit;

ods output clear;
```

But the best answer is don't do this in the first place, use BY groups instead.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class; by sex; run;

ods output ParameterEstimates = want2;
proc reg data=class;
by sex;
model height = weight;
run;
```

EDIT: you can use `ods output` or `ods table`, but I used both in this example and modified it to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the output from each run; you will have to save them to the same data set by appending your results. So, use `PROC APPEND`.

Note: I moved Your ODS Output and Proc append inside your loop, so the ods table will be appended with each loop:

Code:

```
/*Create an empty base table*/
proc sql;
create table WORK.ods_output
  (
   score1_N num format=BEST1. label='N',
   score1_Mean num format=BEST12. label='Mean',
   score1_StdDev num format=BEST12. label='Std Dev',
   score1_Min num format=BEST12. label='Minimum',
   score1_Max num format=BEST12. label='Maximum'
  );
quit;

%MACRO DO_MEAN;
%DO I = 1 %TO 10;
 PROC MEANS data = scores;
 VAR score1;
 TITLE "Average math score";
 RUN;

ods output Summary = Summary;
proc append base=ods_output data=summary; quit;
%END;

%MEND DO_MEAN; 

%DO_MEAN;
```

Output table with 10 rows: (ignore the log warnings)

```
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132 
score1_N=2 score1_Mean=1073.5 score1_StdDev=82.731493399 score1_Min=1015 score1_Max=1132
```