# Is there a way to make multiple proc surveylogistic estimate statements only output one table?

Tags: sas

I have a question about the output from SAS proc surveylogistic when using estimate statements (I think the issue is the same with normal proc logistic too). When I've got an interaction term and I write multiple estimate statements to estimate my ORs, SAS is outputting multiple tables, one for each estimate statement. Here's example code, it will result in three separate estimate tables, one per statement:

```
proc surveylogistic data=dataset nomcar;
    class y / param=ref;
    model outcome (ref='0')= x y z x*y;
    weight weight;
    strata strata;
    cluster PSU;
    domain insubset;
    estimate 'OR for y=1 (vs y=0) @ level 1 of x' y 1 x*y 1 0 / exp cl;
    estimate 'OR for y=1 (vs y=0) @ level 2 of x' y 1 x*y 0 1 / exp cl;
    estimate 'OR for y=1 (vs y=0) @ level 3 of x' y 1 / exp cl;
run;
```

Assume y is dichotomous and x is a 3 level categorical variable.

If I do ODS TRACE, I can see they all have the same name:

```
Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Estimates
Label:      Estimate
Template:   Stat.SurveyLogistic.Estimates
Path:       Surveylogistic.Domain2.Estimates.Estimates
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Estimates
Label:      Estimate
Template:   Stat.SurveyLogistic.Estimates
Path:       Surveylogistic.Domain2.Estimates.Estimates
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Estimates
Label:      Estimate
Template:   Stat.SurveyLogistic.Estimates
Path:       Surveylogistic.Domain2.Estimates.Estimates
```

Is there any way to do multiple estimate statements and have them be output in the same table?

Edit: I believe this question differs from the suggested duplicate because my question involves one procedure producing multiple tables of the same name while the other question is concerned with multiple iterations of a procedure. Mine also concerns the displayed SAS results, as opposed to output datasets. However, in the end, I gave up on trying to change how the results are displayed and just dealt with the output datasets anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS: how to save multiple ODS output from a %DO loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523197/sas-how-to-save-multiple-ods-output-from-a-do-loop)

Comment: PERSIST=PROC is what you want, see the link above for an example with code.

Comment: The PERSIST option didn't affect how the results were displayed. However, even though the results are displayed in the SAS output with separate tables for each estimate statement, ODS OUTPUT Estimates = dataset produces one dataset with all the estimates. This is true even without the PERSIST option, so I just did that. Would like to have the SAS output be more readable, but not a huge deal.